# Dynamic amount of entries in GUI using java

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm working on creating a basic user interface and I wanted to try and create a portion that is in a scrollTaskPane and is capable of holding multiple entries. As I'm going about creating it I can obviously test it with a simple amount of entries but I'm confused how I can go about later allowing for it to take input to create entries in the scrollTaskPane of maybe 1 entry one time, and then later needing to allow for input of 20 entries. I only know how to use absolute positioning and am trying to figure out the best way to go about it. I also need to later be able to select each entry.
For the entries that will eventually be called and displayed in my interface, I'm planning to store them in a simple text file and use a semicolon as a delimiter between the task "Type" "Name" "Description"(which will be accessible through a button) and "Due Date". Or I may try to learn to use a database for the information. But I haven't decided yet and don't know anything about connecting a database with a java program.
[image]

This is the current look (the scrollTaskPane in the middle). And my goal is to put in entries that are each rectangle boxes going across the scrollTaskPane with a checkbox on the end of them. Should I use some sort of grid layout? Or something else? I'm a beginner at user interfaces, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom layout, and then keep adding those layout. So extend a layout class, add `TextField` and a check box in the layout. Initialize the layout with your values, add then add to the `ScrollTaskPane`.

Comment: I had not thought of this idea! Thank you, I will try that. However, when I add the item to the scrollTaskPane will it know to place it below the previous entry or will it try to place it in the same place? How do I go about specifying placement?

Comment: add those layouts in a JList and the JList to the scroll pane or use a boxLayout may be look at [this example of layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or [JList with text boxes](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5342)